# Create more then one jquery html instance

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to have two or more jquery html instances? Example:

```
var me = $('<div>Hello</div>');

$("#go1").append(me);
$("#go2").append(me); //append is the wrong solution. It takes it from "#go1"

me.text("World");
```

There should be two divs with the Word "World" in it.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eam5p/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

use **[.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)**:

```
$("#go1").append(me);
$(me).clone().appendTo("#go2");
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eam5p/6/)**

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eam5p/9/)**

Comment: Both "#go" should have the word "World" in it.

Comment: @bergman you are defining `me` as "World" AFTER you appended it. You can put `me.text("World");` above the append, just keep in mind that in your current code it will overwrite `'<div>Hello</div>'`

Comment: The ".class" way is nice. But i thought there is a method like appendlink(). Because my object is more detailed...

Comment: you should first change the text and then clone and append it.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is the shortest way possible:

```
$("#go1, #go2").append(me.append("World"));
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eam5p/7/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use [clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).
And than your could should be:

```
$("#go1").append(me.clone());
$("#go2").append(me.clone());
```